# jQuery Find and List all LI elements within a UL within a specific DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, children

I have 3 Columns of ULs each a Dynamic UL container that can have anywhere from 0-9 LI containers (eventually more). All my LI elements have an attribute "rel" which I am trying to ultimately find that attribute and use it for something else on all LI elements within that parent DIV. I do eventually want to find more based on each but for not the very least the rel.. Any Ideas how I can achieve that with jQuery? Example:

```
<ul id="column1">
   <li rel="1">Info</li>
   <li rel="2">Info</li>
   <li rel="3">Info</li>
</ul>
<ul id="column2">
   <li rel="4">Info</li>
   <li rel="5">Info</li>
   <li rel="6">Info</li>
</ul>
<ul id="column3">
   <li rel="7">Info</li>
   <li rel="8">Info</li>
   <li rel="9">Info</li>
</ul>
```

these elements are all sortable as well. So when I get a list of them I want to also keep them in the order they were found from top to bottom of each column.

I have tried find(), parent(), and similar, maybe I am approaching it wrong. But its still worth mentioning to help come up with an idea

Comment: are you trying to select by rel? Or get an array of rels?

Comment: trying to form an array of rels per column.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Are you thinking about something like this?

```
$('ul li').each(function(i)
{
   $(this).attr('rel'); // This is your rel value
});
```

Comment: this will work only if your html page contains one 'ul' elemet, what if i've different 'ul' element and i don't want to get id of this.

Answer (score 16):

```
var column1RelArray = [];
$('#column1 li').each(function(){
    column1RelArray.push($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

or fp style

```
var column1RelArray = $('#column1 li').map(function(){ 
    return $(this).attr('rel'); 
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to retrieve each li element id separately from the array? so that i can use to apply some css to one of the id

Comment: Please ask a new question in stack overflow. These are not comments, but further questions.

Answer (score 6):

html

```
<ul class="answerList" id="oneAnswer">
    <li class="answer" value="false">info1</li>
    <li class="answer" value="false">info2</li>
    <li class="answer" value="false">info3</li>
</ul>
```

Get index,text,value
js

```
    $('#oneAnswer li').each(function (i) {

        var index = $(this).index();
        var text = $(this).text();
        var value = $(this).attr('value');
        alert('Index is: ' + index + ' and text is ' + text + ' and Value ' + value);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('li[rel=7]').siblings().andSelf();

// or:

$('li[rel=7]').parent().children();
```

---

Now that you added that comment explaining that you want to "form an array of rels per column", you should do this:

```
var rels = [];

$('ul').each(function() {
    var localRels = [];

    $(this).find('li').each(function(){
        localRels.push( $(this).attr('rel') );
    });

    rels.push(localRels);
});
```