# JQuery : Finding ID attribute of an element in the unordered list without using .each()

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to find id of ul which doesnot have any li element in code below:

```
if ( $("#myDiv ul.myClass > li").length < 1 ){
     alert($(this).attr("id"));
    }
```

I also saw [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101945/jquery-find-and-list-all-li-elements-within-a-ul-within-a-specific-div) but it uses .each() function.
I want to achieve this without using any looping. Is this possible?

**[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/QJt6v/)**

In the JSFiddle above, I am unable to get the ID of the empty UL element. 
It is alerting that it is undefined.

Could anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you want to use .each??

Comment: @RobertRozas: No specific reason. Just wanted to try in a single line if it is possible rather than using loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check using `:empty` selector:

```
 alert($("#myDiv ul:empty").attr("id"));
```

But if more than one, this will returns only ID of the first matched one.

EDIT: your HTML is not valid in jsFiddle. LI cannot be direct child of DIV.

Comment: Yeah you are correct. I just created sample fiddle without noticing that LI cannot be direct child of DIV. Thanks for your response.

Comment: The jsFiddle works fine but my application uses jquery 1.4.2 in which I am still unable to find the id. It shows undefined when I used .attr("id"). Could you please help?

Comment: even using jq 1.4.2, code works. So your issue is coming from somewhere else. Check your console. But its quite strange you accepted answer using `.prop()`, jq 1.4.2 doesn't support it...

Comment: The fiddle was working fine. Hence, I accepted the solution. But, I saw that .prop is not supported in jq 1.4.2. Hence, I used your .attr instead of .prop. But not sure, why it is not working in my application

Comment: @MrudangVora so, is it working now? See working demo, using jq 1.4.2: http://jsfiddle.net/QJt6v/4/

Comment: No it isn't. I tried to alert length `alert($("#myDiv .MyClass > ul:empty").length);` which is coming 1 in fiddle but in my app it is coming as 0.

Comment: That's means element not available in DOM at that time or selector wrong. Now you have to provide more relevant code in question as HTML markup and maybe online link where your issue can be seen. BTW, is it dynamic elements you are tageting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48953/discussion-between-mrudang-vora-and-a-wolff)

Answer (score 2):

In your posted jsFiddle you have a bad selector to start.  You want the `.myClass` to come before the `UL`.

If you fix that, then all you have to do is:

```
alert($("#myDiv > .myClass > ul:empty").prop('id'));
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJt6v/3/)

There are simpler derivations of the selector that would also work:

- `#myDiv .myClass ul:empty` - No Immediate inheritence
- `.myClass ul:empty` - Any instance of ul:empty that is a descendant of .myClass
- `#myDiv ul:empty` - All empty ul's in myClass

Comment: Actually, I wanted to select all the UL elements under element with class = "myClass". Hence, I wrote ul.myClass so that I am able to get all UL elements. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Based on your example `ul.myClass` will always be empty.  My selector will select all UL elements that are under an element with `.myClass` that are under `#myDiv`.  Of the examples, the second is the closest you've described, just add the `>` in between if you want directly below.

Comment: The jsFiddle works fine but my application uses jquery 1.4.2 in which I am still unable to find the id. It shows undefined when I used .attr("id"). Could you please help?